# Showing all points of point cloud layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, las, point-cloud

I have a point cloud file of some trees. I first convert this to a LAS using some converter tool. I then open this LAS file in ArcGIS Pro and somehow it doesn't show all points there is. Even if I set the maximum points to 20.000.000.

My goal is to publish these point cloud to ArcGIS Online. But I can't do that if ArcGIS Pro can't show all the points.

What to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Where did you get the point cloud data from? What format was your point cloud in before you converted it? What tool did you use to do the conversion? You're going to want to look at the metadata to see if something important (i.e. coordinate system) is missing.

Comment: I got it from a colleague who converted it from a navisworks to a .pts. I used cloudcompare to convert it from a .pts to a LAS. I already defined the projection system. I uploaded it to AGOL and there are even way less points to be shown. There is apparently a maximum of points. 
How to get around this ?